# Computing power of a t-test knowing or not the true standard deviation

Tags: t-test, statistical-power

If I have a t-test for the mean of a gaussian population, with $H_1: \mu \neq \mu_0$ and I want to compute its power, analytically, for a certain value $\mu_1$ of $\mu$, hwo do I deal with the standard deviation? If I don't know it can I leave the $S$ that I have from my data? And if instead I want to compute the power also for a specific value of $\sigma$? If I replace $S$ with $\sigma$, then the distribution of the test statistics $T_0$ becomes normal: should I then use this fact in the computation of the power, so that it becomes the probability of a standard normal r.v. being in the t-test critical region?

Comment: $t$ doesn't depend on the SD.   But you can't replace the $S$ with $\sigma,$ since you don't know $\sigma.$  All we're talking about is how to represent the data: if they are lengths, for instance, whether to record them in microns or feet or light-years.  It's irrelevant, so pick whatever unit you like and proceed from there.

Comment: @whuber Maybe my question is not completely clear, but when I want to compute the power I might want to do it for a specific value of $\mu$, and what if I want to do it also for a specific $\sigma$? In this case, if I want to take into account the $\sigma$, the distribution becomes normal, but then I am not sure I am still computing the power of the t-test

Comment: Power analysis concerns suppositions about population properties and is based on a planned statistical test.  In your case, you would answer questions of the form "if the population mean is $\mu$ and the population SD is $\sigma$ and I conduct a Student t test of $H_0:\mu=\mu_0$ against the alternative $H_A:\mu\ne\mu_0,$ what is the chance I will reject the null?"  Because that chance depends only on the sample size and the *standard effect size* $E = (\mu-\mu_0)/\sigma,$ you only need to search over the one-dimensional space of values of $E.$